# Send HTTP traffic to VPN

Tags: macos, vpn, ipfw

I want to encrypt my unencrypted HTTP traffic by sending them to VPN. I tried to use this IPFW rule, but it is not seem working (I dont see traffic on VPN connection).

```
allow ip from any to any dst-port 80 out via ppp0
```

PPTP connection is established correctly.

EDIT: It seems IPFW is not good tool for this case. Could you recommend any other solution?

Comment: well, from what I know of ipfw, it either block or allows, and I don't know of it having a method to forward.. (though maybe i'm wrong there), but all that line you give will do is not deny it. Meaning, that if you weren't running ipfw, you'd get the same effect. So if you have to forward to a vpn, then you'd definitely need a different command and probably a different program than ipfw. That line just says, if it's going out that interface let it out! also, there is a unix.stackexchange site

Comment: also you'd need one going in too.. if that works then forget those two rules and replace them with a snazzy one with keep-state and check-state.

Comment: i'm not even sure your command will work. specifying port with ip. do you not get an error? try these two  `ipfw add allow tcp from any to any 80 out` and `ipfw add allow tcp from any 80 to any in`  if they work then go for `ipfw add 10 check-state` `ipfw add 100 allow tcp from any to any 80 setup keep-state`  I know some ipfw but not the vpn aspect. And you can add the via ppp0 aspect.